# Compare value in for loop

Tags: java, loops

I'm doing 2 random card generator. I want to know which is higher. How can I compare the current value to previous value in the following example?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    String suit = suits[deck[i] / 13];
    String rank = ranks[deck[i] % 13];
    System.out.println("You have the " + rank + " of " + suit);                 
}
```

Comment: you want to compare between the suit and the rank and take the higher of them is that right ??

Comment: why don't you store the previous value in a variable and then compare it with the 2nd value?

Answer (score 0):

```
String previousValue = null;
for(...) {
    String currentValue = ...;

    // you can now compare previous with current, watch out for unset (null)
    if( previousValue != null && currentValue (?) previousValue ) {...}

    //... any further processing

    // following is the last line in your loop, so it is set for next loop iteration
    previousValue = currentValue;
}
```